# Looking for information about "Hebrew Letter" layout (at LyX)

Tags: lyx, letters, hebrew, lyx-layouts

When I look at layouts of LyX 2.2 I saw "Hebrew Letter", I looked for information on the internet but nothing was found.
Can you help me please and give some information or sources that I can read about it more?

[image: The layout]
[image: The options at the menu]

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout makes some simple changes for alignment to the base letter layout. You can see how it is defined in the file lib/layouts/heb-letter.layout:

```
#% Do not delete the line below; configure depends on this
#  \DeclareLaTeXClass[letter]{Hebrew Letter}
#  \DeclareCategory{Letters}
# Hebrew letter textclass definition file.
# Author: Dekel Tsur <dekel@math.tau.ac.il>

Format 62
Input letter


Style My_Address
    Align                 Left
End


Style Send_To_Address
    Align                 Right
End
```